# Cross platform Game frameworks with good speed

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, cross-platform, game-engine

I have to develop the game so that with same code (or may be few lines of change in code) will works in ANDRIOID and IOS, Blackberry (optional) or Windows (if possible).

My Objectives are:-

> 1. Most important - I need to package as native apps
> 2. Good graphics speed with HTML5 and CSS3 or may be some other language
> 3. Provide Gaming Engine needs (a native engine like Unity 3D or Cocos
> 4. Optional - can they do more than Android/IOS - like Tablet, Windows Phone, BB10, and  > Desktop (Browser/Windows App store app)

Can anyone help me to evaluate which is best

> 1. PhoneGap
> 2. appMobi
> 3. Ludei
> 4. Corona
> 5. GameSalad
> 6. Shiva
> 7. Unity
> 8. Stencyl
> 9. Marmalade may be something else?

Right now I am open for 2D simple games but yes in future I also need to work on 3d context based games too.

Comment: Please read the FAQ on what types of questions can be asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://mobilegameengines.com/ (besides being an ad for JB's book ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*PhoneGap* isn't a 2D/gaming JS framework. It will help you just to build the bridge between your JS code and the native controllers of your device.

*GameSalad* isn't so bad but not really flexible. If you want to do advanced stuff, you'll feel stuck in its environment.

*Cocos2D* released a JS framework that works pretty well 
http://cocos2d-javascript.org/

Or *GameQuery* with a lot of impressive demos 
http://gamequeryjs.com/